# How can I use flashvars parameters with iframe?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, flashvars

I have a self-hosted wordpress blog and I'm trying to embed a video with the code on the website:

```
<iframe src="http://www.viki.com/player/medias/80715" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360"</iframe>
```

It works fine however, the video has an autoplay feature which plays the next video automatically and I'd like it to just stop at the end. Also, the video has subtitles which defaults to English and I'd like the Spanish ones to load instead of the English ones.

I'm able to achieve that with this code:

```
<embed src="http://a3.vikiassets.com/swfs/vikiplayer.swf?1320909340" flashvars="language_codes=es&amp;source=direct&amp;media_id=80715" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen="true"</embed>
```

but, is there any way to achieve that with iframe?

Comment: Does the iframe link accept query string parameters

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work so I guess it doesn't accept any. Any way to achieve that without query strings?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have any luck with this? I've got a similar issue but it is not as tidy as I would like.

I have a page on `domain1.com` which has an `iFrame` with this code loading the Flash file from another server - `domain2.com`.

`index.html` file on `domain1.com`:

```
<iframe name="iframe"  src="http://www.domain2.com/iframe.php?var1=myvar" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" height="600" width="970">
</iframe>
```

On `domain2.com` the iFrame code is a PHP page and requests the variable like this:

```
<?php $var1 = ($_REQUEST['var1']);

<object... (Flash embed etc)
<param name=FlashVars value="var1=<?php echo $var1;?>" />
```

I can load in many Flash variables to control the Flash file over different servers but ideally I'd like to iframe in an `swf` with the query string but this seems to do the trick.

If you had a better solution it would be good to see.
Thanks.